# Unable to start kafka with zookeeper (kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException)

Tags: windows, kafka, zookeeper

Below the steps I did to get this issue :

1. Launch ZooKeeper
2. Launch Kafka : `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties`

***Also note that my OS is Windows***

And at the second step the error happens :

> ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
>   (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
>   kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: **The Cluster ID
>   Reu8ClK3TTywPiNLIQIm1w doesn't match stored clusterId
>   Some(BaPSk1bCSsKFxQQ4717R6Q) in meta.properties. The broker is trying
>   to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.**
>           at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:220)
>           at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
>           at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84)
>           at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

When I trigger `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties` **zookeeper** console returns :

> INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@216] - Creating new log file: log.1

How to fix this issue to get kafka running ?

**EDIT** See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832914/11167163) following those steps solved my problem

Comment: I suspect it's a problem with Kafka 2.4.0:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592518/kafka-broker-doesnt-find-cluster-id-and-creates-new-one-after-docker-restart

Answer (score 15):

I solved this issue on my machine (Windows 10) by deleting the meta.properties file found in the log directory.

The issue itself occured after I had stopped both the zookeeper and server and then restarted them.

Comment: the logs are in /tmp directory

Comment: Good for you @johnmin The file I removed still was in the logs directory.

Comment: Yes, it will get generated again, but Kafka will start without issues

Comment: @johnmin ok. I never claimed it wouldn't. Obviously the old file was the problem and the newly generated one worked fine. The removed file was in the logs directory.

Answer (score 11):

Usually, this problem arises when kafka logs are stored in the persistent folder and zookeeper data in the temporary, or vice-versa.
Then, after system restart, files that are stored in the temporary directory get cleaned and regenerated leading to the configuration mismatch.

To prevent this situation to happen again revise `log.dirs` kafka parameter in the `server.properties` and `dataDir` zookeeper parameter in `zookeeper.properties` and ensure that both point to the same type of directory (e.g. temporary or persistent). Only after that reset inconsistent data (if any) using for example method from Jacob's answer, i.e. remove `meta.properties` file, and restart zookeeper and kafka.

Comment: hehe, second time I end up here. Thanks mate! Any advantages in choosing tmp over persistent?

Comment: This answer saved me.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue while running Kafka server on my Windows Machine. You can try the following to resolve this issue:

1. Open server server.properties file which is located in your kafka folder kafka_2.11-2.4.0\config (considering your version of kafka, folder name could be kafka_<kafka_version>)
2. Search for entry log.dirs
3. If your log.dir path contains windows directory path like this E:\Shyam\Software\kafka_2.11-2.4.0\kafka-logs which has a single backslash i.e , change it to double back-slash i.e with \

Answer (score 1):

**Try the following...**

1. Enable following line in ./config/server.properties

   listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
2. Modify default ZooKeeper dataDir
3. Modify default Kafka log dir

Answer (score 1):

On windows version 20H2 and OS build 19042.662 escaping the **log.dirs** path in **<kafka_dir>\config** directory worked for me.

it was previously

```
log.dirs=C:\*********\kafka\logs
```

changed to

```
log.dirs=C:\\*********\\kafka\\logs
```

Might need to restart zookeeper first and then kafka after the change.

Answer (score 1):

No need to delete the log/data files on Kafka. Check the Kafka error logs and find the new cluster id. Update the meta.properties file with cluster-ID then restart the Kafka.

```
/home/kafka/logs/meta.properties
```

**To resolve this issue permanently follow below.**

Check your zookeeper.properties file and look for `dataDir`path and change the path `tmp` location to any other location which should not be removed after server restart.

```
/home/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
```

Copy the zookeeper folder and file to the new(below or non tmp) location then restart the zookeeper and Kafka.

```
cp -r /tmp/zookeeper /home/kafka/zookeeper
```

Now server restart won’t affect the Kafka startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind losing your data than you can remove your kafka "data" folder and restart kafka. If you used the default location the folder named "data"  is probably in /tmp/kafka-logs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the path of my log file in server.properties is `log.dirs=C:\\Users\\Dorian\\kafka_2.12-2.4.0\\kafka-logs` is it wrong ?

Comment: I also have no data folder into `kafka_2.12-2.4.0` so how should i set up the data folder path ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to **delete kafka-logs from your tmp folder**, which is **located in C:/tmp** folder by default on windows, and can be set in [your-kafka-folder]/config/server.properties file as log.dirs

Answer (score 0):

Delete /tmp/kafka-logs/meta.properties which saved the wrong cluster.id of last/failed session:

```
#
broker.id=0
version=0
cluster.id=kzRHvVl-Rb2DZaHSqlTfow     <===
```